# How can I precompile multiple vue files in a single library and keep them easily importable?

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack

I have a program with multiple `.vue` files in `src/components`. These use typescript and sass. The program uses webpack for compilation and bundling. I would like to add all these components to a single npm package to be used as a library with the following restrictions:

- It should be compiled down to javascript and css so whoever imports my library doesn't need my compile dependencies and webpack configuration
- The components depend on typescript files. These should also be compiled, but not bundled. They are valid entry points for the library.
- The import for the users of the library should be as painless as possible. It would be optimal if the generated js and css could be loaded in a single import, just like importing a `.vue` file

Is this possible to do? And if so, how? If not, how could I best approximate this or what are my alternatives?

I have tried to use `vue-cli-service build --target lib` but it seems that can only handle one component, bundles the ts files, and I'm not sure if it behaves like I expect when you import a file.